# Android: my maps doesn't go to "my location"

Tags: android, maps, location

i've created a map, but when on the phone, it doesn't move to my location (taken from gps). why?
Because i need to retrieve the user location, and in case i've found it, animate the map to that point and refresh it (to take the pin from the db). in negative case, i put the center to Milano.

```
public class Mappa extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
double latitudine=0;
double longitudine=0;
int kilometri=20;
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mappa);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    final MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_bioscalin);
    MyOverlays itemizedoverlay = new MyOverlays(drawable, this);
    // milano
    latitudine = 45.464164;
    longitudine = 9.190321;
    GeoPoint mio_point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitudine*1E6), (int)(longitudine*1E6));
    mapController.setCenter(mio_point);
    mapController.animateTo(mio_point);
    mapController.setZoom(11);
    // GPS
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    // farmacie
    Database_mio db=new Database_mio(this); 
    db.openDataBase(); 
    Cursor data=db.elenco_negozi_mappa(latitudine,longitudine,kilometri);
    data.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String id_farmacia = data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String ragione_farmacia = data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndex("ragione"));
        String indirizzo_farmacia = data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndex("ragione"));
        int latitude_farmacia = (int) (data.getDouble(data
                .getColumnIndex("lat")) * 1E6);
        int longitude_farmacia = (int) (data.getDouble(data
                .getColumnIndex("lng")) * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude_farmacia,longitude_farmacia);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,ragione_farmacia,indirizzo_farmacia);
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    } while (data.moveToNext());
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    // disclamer
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_mia_map);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent disclamer = new Intent(getParent(), Disclamer.class);
            disclamer.putExtra("da_dove", "Mappa");
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Disclamer", disclamer);
        }
    });
}
/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "La mia posizione: "+"Latitudine = "+loc.getLatitude()+"Longitudine = "+loc.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint mio_point = new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(loc.getLongitude()*1E6));
        mapView.getController().setCenter(mio_point);
        mapView.getController().animateTo(mio_point);
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps disabilitato",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps abilitato",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){

    }
}
}
```

thanks to all.

Comment: did you provided permission in manifest regarding GPS

Comment: ok it works, but it takes a lot of time to display the location!!! the gps is slow!
p.s. the invalidate function let the maps reload? and so, the query for the pin is re-done?

Comment: gps provider takes time to fetch location and it works outdoors efficiently.

Comment: ok, it works. but for reload and re-do the query?